# Where can I find pulumi aws.apigateway.x Documentation

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway, pulumi

Just starting out with some pulumi.io tutorials and immediately encountered

```
const endpoint = new aws.apigateway.x.API("hello", {...})
```

Then I went to the [pulumi aws.apigateway documentation](https://pulumi.io/reference/pkg/nodejs/@pulumi/aws/apigateway/) and don't see anything about the mysterious `apigateway.x` component.

Where can I find the docs for this? The only goog/ddg real hit I could find is a single sentence in the [0.16.0 release notes](https://pulumi.io/reference/changelog.html#pulumiaws-0160):

> In addition, the aws.apigateway.x.API type is available for simple construction of API Gateways directly in the @pulumi/aws package.

Ok, so it's a different type for simple construction. Where can I go for more in depth context? It's also not in the API docs—do I just use the regular non `x` prefixed `.API` docs?

What's the difference between `apigateway.x.API` and `apigateway.API`?

Answer (score 0):

Figured I'd take a look at the actual code (go figure, right?) and found that `apigateway.x.API` is now under `awsx.apigateway.API`. Was wondering if `awsx` was related. Feel better now.

https://github.com/pulumi/pulumi-aws/pull/508

> The deprecated api aws.apigateway.x.API has been removed. Its replacement is in the @pulumi/awsx package with the name awsx.apigateway.API.

`pulumi-awsx` is described as "AWS infrastructure best practices in component form.

https://github.com/pulumi/pulumi-awsx